# How to close Spring beans properly after received a SIGTERM?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to keep my application *alive* in order to *listen* for some messages from my `queue`. However, once my application receives a `SIGTERM`, I would like to ensure that my application shutdown nicely. Meaning, ensure that the jobs, internally, has finished first, before the shutdown.

After reading about it , I came up with this:

```
@Component
public class ParserListenerStarter {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ParserReceiveJmsContext.class);
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        System.out.println("Listening...");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( //
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Closing parser listener gracefully!");
                        context.close();
                    }
                });

        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

Then I send a `kill` command to my application; and this is my output:

```
Listening...
// output from my other beans here
Closing parser listener gracefully!

Process finished with exit code 143 (interrupted by signal 15: SIGTERM)
```

The `shutdown` methods from my beans were not called:

```
@PreDestroy public void shutdown() {..}
```

I'm not an expert in `Spring`, so I'm sorry for any silly point that I'm missing here.

How can I `shutdown` my beans and then close my application nicely ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need:

```
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

So, add the code above and then your @PreDestroy method will be invoked.
After that you don't need to do anything else. It means you <s>must</s> can delete

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( //
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Closing parser listener gracefully!");
                    context.close();
                }
            });
```

**EDIT:**
[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) says that you can have multiple shutdown hooks:

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start **all registered shutdown hooks**

So the statement below is incorrect:

<s>When you added this, you replaced the Spring hook, which do the beans destroying, because internally, method looks like</s>

```
if (this.shutdownHook == null) {
        // No shutdown hook registered yet.
        this.shutdownHook = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doClose();
            }
        };
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(this.shutdownHook);
    }
```

Comment: You're right Nikolay! Thank you very much for your answer!